# Using json inputs in Playframework

Tags: playframework

So I pass parameters, including one Json one, to one of views:

```
val json: JsValue = Json.toJson(ResultJson.staticResULT)
Ok(views.html.main("")(StaticContent.initialFormContent, json))
```

and here is how I receive it in the view:

```
@import play.api.libs.json.JsValue
@import play.api.libs.json.JsString
@(title: String)(formContent: FormContent, solverResponse: JsValue = JsString(""))
```

I want to convert `solverResponse` to json inside the javascript:

```
var solverLogJson = JSON.parse("@solverResponse.toString()");
```

when I do this, the browser complains that:

```
VM11598:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & in JSON at position 1(…)
```

Printing the Json it's clear that the quotes " are converted to `&quot;`. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [escaping raw HTML content](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTemplates#Escaping), you need to wrap the string in an `@Html` call to pass it correctly to a javascript method, i.e.

```
var solverLogJson = JSON.parse("@Html(solverResponse.toString())");
```

This method of passing JSON values via arguments is a bit cludgy, however, I'd suggest creating a separate endpoint that returns JSON and using an ajax call to load the JSON in your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If it is valid, json, you can use @josephconley's answer, and just cast it as Html.

```
var solverLogJson = @Html(solverResponse.toString);
```

Since json is valid javascript, you shouldn't need to parse it again using `JSON.parse`.